# SqlException not working in C#

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, sqlexception

I am trying to use the sqlException handler, but it is not working.  Tried researching and reviewing everything I know.  Using Visual Studio 2017 (latest update), Xamarin, .net 4.7, Windows 10 creators updates.  I am using the correct package, but it is not recognized.  My code is below.  I either must be missing something, or am not seeing something, but this should work as intended.  The standard Exception works, but the SqlException is not recognized.  Please help.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;

namespace MobileWebServices.SqlClientFiles
{
    public partial class SqlClient
    {
        private int GetMaxECMDataID(string tClientNumber, string tClientPassCode, string tFileID)
        {
            int maxECMDataID = 0;
            var tempConnection = GetTempConnection();
            try
            {
                tempConnection.Open();
                string SQLString = "SELECT max(ECMDataID) as mECMDataID FROM ECMData WHERE FileId = " + "'" + tFileID + "'" + " and iPadLocation = " +
                  "'" + tClientNumber + "'" + " and licensePassCode = " + "'" + tClientPassCode + "'";
                var sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(SQLString, tempConnection);
                maxECMDataID = (int)sqlcommand.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not recognized"?  What is the *specific* error you're seeing?

Comment: what is the 3rd using (using System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException;) SqlException is a class not a namespace

Comment: Your catch is empty so if one is raised what do you want to do? (You are vulnerable to injection so this should be refactored to use SqlParameters)

Answer (score 0):

Works as expected on my machine. If you copy the line from the Exception block into the SqlException catch block, you should see output. In my case, I get

`The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.`

Comment: figured it out.  Since we are using partial classes, the SqlException gets resolved at build/compile time.  Took out the class, figured that out shortly after the post.  Everything is working.